# Rails Check if the request host the same with the local host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm looking for the way to check if the request from the outside or it's local.

The problem that I've faced on is that I can not in the right way detect root host (host where the server is hosted).

I've found **request.referrer**, property and may it can help me to solve the issue, partially. I'm not sure that it is the best way to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try `request.host` in your controller. And look here
[Request](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html)

Comment: Yes, you right. When the request comes, I'm trying to get it in that way. 
For example my server host is "server:80",  client host is "client:80". 
How can I check whether the host is server host or not? Without direct condition like request.host == "server"